# Nested dropdrown menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to build a nested dropdown menu with javascript and click event. My html is this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="menu-item-439" class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">hostelería</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-459">
                <a href="#">Comanderos</a>
            </li>
           <li id="menu-item-457" class="dropdown">
               <a href="#">Venta online</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                   <li>
                       <a href="#">PortalRest Pedidos</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and my javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown').forEach(i => {
    i.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        i.classList.toggle('show');
    })
});
```

The problem is in the nested "dropdown" class. When i click in "child dropdown" (id="menu-item-457") toogle not only affects that element but also affects the parent (id="menu-item-439")

Thanks!!

Comment: There were mistakes in your code, for ex. you didn't need to make every element to toggle, just making one parent element toggle is enough, check my code if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id="menu-item-439" class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle()">hostelería</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-459">
                <a href="#">Comanderos</a>
            </li>
           <li id="menu-item-457" class="dropdown">
               <a href="#"  onclick="toggle2()">Venta online</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                   <li>
                       <a href="#">PortalRest Pedidos</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

JS

```
let n=0, n2=0;

function toggle() {
n++;
if (n%2==0) {
document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu")[0].style.display="none";
}
else {
document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu")[0].style.display="block";

}
}
function toggle2() {
n2++;
if (n2%2==0) {
document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu")[1].style.display="none";
}
else {
document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu")[1].style.display="block";

}
}
```

CSS

```
.sub-menu {display: none}
```

If you wanted same with JQuery toggle method, then js should be like this

JS

```
function toggle() {
document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu")[0].toggle();
}
function toggle2() {
document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu")[1].toggle();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! The problem is that it is a menu made in wordpress and the menu is dynamic. From wordpress you can put a class in each <li> but you can't add more. My idea was that the administrator (who doesn't know programming) add the dropdown class and the system builds the necessary dropdowns, I don't know if it's possible.

Thank you very much

Comment: Ah OK, then I can't help you there, cause I didn't ever use wordpress